# Delphi TChromeTabs not working in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

So I use Delphi XE and I wanted to install TChromeTabs (http://www.easy-ip.net/tchrometabs.html) or (https://github.com/norgepaul/TChromeTabs) since it seems to do what I need.

First of all, the component does not have a Delphi XE package, so I thought I could try to use the package built for XE2, then when it gave me the error, I tried the package built for Delphi 7. Same result.

I mean, the installation of the component worked just fine, the component shows up on my pallette, but if I want to drop the component on my form, I get an AccessViolation at address 00000000. The details say:

```
[422A1207]{Tee9150.bpl } Gdipapi.TGdiplusBase.NewInstance + $B
[5003A753]{rtl150.bpl  } System.@ClassCreate (Line 12121, "System.pas" + 5) + $0
[422B3CE2]{Tee9150.bpl } Gdipobj.TGPPen + $E
[11AE5CF5]{ChromeTabs_XE2_R.bpl} ChromeTabsControls.TBaseChromeButtonControl.GetButtonPen (Line 1897, "ChromeTabsControls.pas" + 2) + $27
[11AE22EF]{ChromeTabs_XE2_R.bpl} ChromeTabsControls.TAddButtonControl.GetPolygons (Line 481, "ChromeTabsControls.pas" + 1) + $4
[50285877]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.GetClientRect (Line 11931, "Controls.pas" + 1) + $9
[5027BF34]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TControl.GetClientWidth (Line 5661, "Controls.pas" + 1) + $6
[11AE1F06]{ChromeTabs_XE2_R.bpl} ChromeTabsControls.TBaseChromeTabsControl.ContainsPoint (Line 318, "ChromeTabsControls.pas" + 3) + $7
[11AEBB0F]{ChromeTabs_XE2_R.bpl} ChromeTabs.TCustomChromeTabs.HitTest (Line 1777, "ChromeTabs.pas" + 9) + $B
[11AE9D3B]{ChromeTabs_XE2_R.bpl} ChromeTabs.TCustomChromeTabs.SetControlDrawStates (Line 819, "ChromeTabs.pas" + 6) + $28
[11AEF5F2]{ChromeTabs_XE2_R.bpl} ChromeTabs.TCustomChromeTabs.Resize (Line 3344, "ChromeTabs.pas" + 9) + $6
[50283788]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.WMSize (Line 10336, "Controls.pas" + 20) + $6
[5027DF6C]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7074, "Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[50037560]{rtl150.bpl  } System.@FreeMem (Line 3768, "System.pas" + 20) + $0
[5003C0B0]{rtl150.bpl  } System.@UStrClr (Line 16968, "System.pas" + 14) + $0
[20B03B6E]{coreide150.bpl} PropInsp.TPropertyInspector.DrawNamePair (Line 731, "PropInsp.pas" + 49) + $19
[5003C167]{rtl150.bpl  } System.@WStrArrayClr (Line 17237, "System.pas" + 9) + $0
[50282830]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9831, "Controls.pas" + 144) + $6
[5025E975]{vcl150.bpl  } Graphics.TCanvas.SetHandle (Line 4170, "Graphics.pas" + 6) + $6
[50282830]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9831, "Controls.pas" + 144) + $6
[500AFA64]{rtl150.bpl  } Classes.StdWndProc (Line 13491, "Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[11AF010E]{ChromeTabs_XE2_R.bpl} ChromeTabs.TCustomChromeTabs.WndProc (Line 3716, "ChromeTabs.pas" + 10) + $4
[50281ED0]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9552, "Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[500AFA64]{rtl150.bpl  } Classes.StdWndProc (Line 13491, "Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[5003ABE2]{rtl150.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 12523, "System.pas" + 9) + $7
[5003AC1B]{rtl150.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 12537, "System.pas" + 2) + $7
[5009E0CE]{rtl150.bpl  } Classes.TInterfaceList.GetCount (Line 4147, "Classes.pas" + 5) + $9
[50040A33]{rtl150.bpl  } System.TInterfacedObject._Release (Line 28243, "System.pas" + 1) + $3
[50040950]{rtl150.bpl  } System.@IntfClear (Line 28061, "System.pas" + 10) + $0
[51B1DD1E]{vcldesigner150.bpl} VCLSurface.TVclDesignSurface.IsDesignMsg (Line 3307, "VCLSurface.pas" + 186) + $28
[50281129]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.Broadcast (Line 8982, "Controls.pas" + 1) + $3
[502811A9]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.NotifyControls (Line 9010, "Controls.pas" + 9) + $2
[5003AEBE]{rtl150.bpl  } System.TMonitor.TryEnter (Line 12708, "System.pas" + 10) + $0
[5003AA38]{rtl150.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Enter (Line 12406, "System.pas" + 4) + $2
[50282830]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9831, "Controls.pas" + 144) + $6
[502532CF]{vcl150.bpl  } Windows.CreateWindowEx (Line 35262, "windows.pas" + 2) + $2A
[502815D4]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.CreateWindowHandle (Line 9225, "Controls.pas" + 1) + $2A
[11AED02A]{ChromeTabs_XE2_R.bpl} ChromeTabs.TCustomChromeTabs.CreateWindowHandle (Line 2291, "ChromeTabs.pas" + 1) + $2
[502814D6]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.CreateWnd (Line 9202, "Controls.pas" + 45) + $A
[5028191A]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.CreateHandle (Line 9340, "Controls.pas" + 3) + $4
[50281BE0]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.UpdateShowing (Line 9463, "Controls.pas" + 7) + $11
[50281C0E]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.UpdateShowing (Line 9466, "Controls.pas" + 10) + $10
[50281D88]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.UpdateControlState (Line 9510, "Controls.pas" + 21) + $3
[50280FE2]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.InsertControl (Line 8903, "Controls.pas" + 25) + $2
[5027C54C]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TControl.SetParent (Line 5873, "Controls.pas" + 9) + $4
[502877B9]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.SetParent (Line 13156, "Controls.pas" + 5) + $5
[51B18803]{vcldesigner150.bpl} VCLSurface.TControlItem.SetParent (Line 897, "VCLSurface.pas" + 1) + $19
[2107A0DF]{designide150.bpl} ComponentDesigner.TComponentRoot.DoCreateComponent (Line 2411, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 99) + $8
[2107F022]{designide150.bpl} ComponentDesigner.TComponentRoot.CreateCurrentComponent (Line 4384, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 2) + $32
[2109636E]{designide150.bpl} Surface.TDesignSurface.CreateItem (Line 187, "Surface.pas" + 1) + $11
[2104E6BE]{designide150.bpl} Designer.TDesigner.DoDragCreate (Line 764, "Designer.pas" + 1) + $F
[2104EE98]{designide150.bpl} Designer.TDesigner.DragEnd (Line 928, "Designer.pas" + 19) + $3
[21051474]{designide150.bpl} Designer.TDesigner.MouseUp (Line 1710, "Designer.pas" + 1) + $2
[51B1CCA1]{vcldesigner150.bpl} VCLSurface.MouseEvent (Line 2908, "VCLSurface.pas" + 45) + $11
[5003AC1B]{rtl150.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 12537, "System.pas" + 2) + $7
[51B1D87B]{vcldesigner150.bpl} VCLSurface.TVclDesignSurface.IsDesignMsg (Line 3169, "VCLSurface.pas" + 48) + $6
[500AFA64]{rtl150.bpl  } Classes.StdWndProc (Line 13491, "Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[5003A336]{rtl150.bpl  } System.@IsClass (Line 11370, "System.pas" + 1) + $8
[5027DCDB]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 6987, "Controls.pas" + 4) + $21
[502820C3]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.IsControlMouseMsg (Line 9608, "Controls.pas" + 1) + $9
[50282830]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9831, "Controls.pas" + 144) + $6
[5034FB28]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.TCustomForm.WndProc (Line 3961, "Forms.pas" + 191) + $5
[50281ED0]{vcl150.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9552, "Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[500AFA64]{rtl150.bpl  } Classes.StdWndProc (Line 13491, "Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[503975EB]{vcl150.bpl  } AppEvnts.TMultiCaster.GetAppEvents (Line 653, "AppEvnts.pas" + 1) + $5
[50358AF7]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 9760, "Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[50358B3A]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 9790, "Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[50358E65]{vcl150.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 9927, "Forms.pas" + 26) + $3
```

I have no idea how to deal with this...
The same error shows up if I uninstall the XE2 package and install the Delphi 7 package. Seems like it all starts with the Tee package somehow... I might be wrong

What should I do in order to get this to work properly and be able to use the component?

Comment: Some info here perhaps: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12346

Comment: Yup, I see now that the same problem arizes for this component TrkSmartTabs (Klever) that does and look similar... maybe they are inspired from one another... http://rmklever.com/?p=273 (in the comments section many complaints about Delphi XE - specifically the GDI+ library that seems to mess things up)

Comment: Perhaps the author can help, @norgepaul

Comment: I succeeded in making it work by renaming the actual GDI+ units, and modifying the component's refferenced units to point to the new GDI+ unit names. I wonder why the creator of the component did not think of that? What should I do with this question? LU RD, if you'd like, make your comment into an Answer and I will accept it

Comment: Go ahead and make it your own answer. Self-answering questions are perfectly ok here. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the solution would be to :

1. rename the files *GDIPAPI.pas, GDIPObj.pas* and *GDIPUtils.pas* located in the component's folder, in the GDIPlus sub-folder. I renamed them by adding a trailing x.
   So I ended up with ***GDIPAPIx.pas, GDIPObjx.pas*** and ***GDIPUtilsx.pas***
2. edit the pas files and replace the name of the unit to the new name, and update the uses clauses to point to the new unit names.
   (I also added the changed pas files to my Lib folder)
3. Compile, Build and Install the component.

If you skip any of the above steps, you will most likely receive all kinds of compiling errors, caused by the fact that the units probably still reffer to the original GDIP files located in your Lib folder already (placed there by Tee most likely). So make sure to replace all refferences inside the units with the new names

I also think that it might work if I only rename the first 2 files, but I am not in the mood for any more testing.

Now it works fine. I can add the control to my form, and I can run my simple test application fine without any errors.

It would be great if it's creator: @norgepaul would solve this problem and create a dpk for delphi XE too.

Comment: I don't have XE, but will be happy to add any fixes you want to send me. Just add an issue in the bug tracker and I will get to it as soon as I have time.

Comment: Please be so kind and give me a link to where I should post the issue and maybe the solution. I do not know where to find the bug tracker you speak of

Comment: However, the solution to any problem like mine is simply to rename the GDI+ units to names that are not used by other libraries, so just don't let them have the same names as now, because they are in conflict with another library that has the same unit names but slightly different content. So just rename the files and the refferences to them and all shall be fine. You don't need an XE version in order to do that. It;s a simple file renaming issue + some uses-clause editing to point to the new units. No big deal